# estimation average response time based on number of requests and resource capacity

Tags: performance, server, response-time

I want to know is it possible to estimate the average response time for a time interval by having the total number of requests and the number of resources and their capacity(request per second) in that time interval?
For example,following equation can be true ?

equation:  average Response time = total number of requests/resource capacity

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The average response time doesn't depend on the number of requests in a time interval.

If you have a fixed resource capacity, then you have a fixed total capacity of

```
   Total_capacity (req/s) = Num_resources * Resource_capacity (req/s)
```

E.g. if you have `5` resources each capable of `5` requests/s, then your max capacity is `5*5=25`. With a constant supply of `26` requests/s, each 26th request will either queue up or be dropped.